# macOS: Is there a way to keep the Emoji & Symbol viewer on top/without disappearing?

Tags: macos, mac, window-manager, emoji

Since I'm not a MacBook Pro /w Touch Bar user, I occasionally use the macOS Emoji & Symbols viewer to double-click various emoji entries into the system. However, the Emoji & Symbols viewer is annoying because it's easily hidden by other application windows, and it seems to disappear once you click outside of the application window and select another app.

I can't find a way to make it "float" on the Desktop, or to prevent it from closing when switching to another app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it opens on a per-app basis.

You can open it twice [or more], in different apps, & it will remember position & settings separately for each & swap between as you switch apps.

It used to be global, a long time ago, but hasn't been for quite some time.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Perhaps I'll look around for a stand-alone emoji app.

Comment: I don't know of one, but it might be worth adding in a comment or answer if you find one.

Comment: @Winterflags Have a look at Ultra Character Map (not free unfortunately)  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ultra-character-map/id520265986?mt=12